# why does the 'error' function of $.ajax execute even when the request to invoke a webmethod succeeds?

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, webmethod

I am using jquery ajax method to invoke a webmethod upon clicking a 'span'.This is webmethod is in one of my aspx pages and I am invoking it from the master page using the following code.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $("#btn").click(function() {
        $.ajax({   
              type: "POST", 
              url: "Default.aspx/removedata",
              data:"{}",
              contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
              dataType: "json",  
              success:function(msg) {  
                   $("li#search").removeClass('current');
                   $("li#search").addClass('hide');
                   $("#tabnew").addClass('hide');
                   window.location="Result.aspx";       
              },
              error:function(xhr, status, error) {
                  alert("error");                       
                  //var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
                  // Display the specific error raised by the server 
                  //alert(err.Message);
                  console.log(xhr.statusText);
              }
          });
       });
    });
```

when I click  the span I can see the webmethod getting invoked(by debugging ),but even before the webmethod starts executing I get the alert 'error' and I see ***(an empty string)***   message being logged into the firebug console.
As far as I know the 'error' function gets executed only if the ajax request fails.But I can see the webmethod getting executed.I do not understand why the error function is executing even then.

Could someone please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: Do you make any url rewrite ?

Comment: no,I am not making url rewrite.actually I am just removing some data stored in the sessions in the webmethods I am invoking.

Comment: I can see the request being made in firebug but once the webmethod completes execution the request doesnt seem to appear any more.So I am unable to see the status/response returned.I tried the ajax call from another aspx page which is not inherited from Master page I see a '200 ok' status returned with a response '{"d":1}',where '1' is the value i am returning from webmethod.

Comment: I do not understand one more thing.as soon as I click the span I get the alert saying 'error' even before I start debugging the execution of webmethod and I also see the session values removed after the execution of the webmthod.

Answer (score 1):

The `error` handler is executed if the server side script returns an error code different than 200. You could use [FireBug](http://www.getfirebug.com/) to inspect what exactly is happening under the covers.

Comment: Fiddler2 (http://www.fiddler2.com/) is also a very helpful tool for knowing precisely what is in the HttpResponse returned from the webservice.